# Drupal 7 - load view programmatically

Tags: 7, views

How do I load a view programmatically passing a language attribute?
Tried with module_invoke and views_embed_view but none of them worked;
Data is returned but not filtered by language;

Please advise.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the code you tried with views_embed_view? Does your view contain a filter for "Users current language"?

Comment: To be more specific: I have a page view for news; when accessing the page directly from browser: "site/news" or "site/fr/news" - the content is rendered correctly.
The problem appears when I try lo load this view programmatically. The English content is always being returned.

Also, in "Filter Criteria" Section: " Content: Language (in Current user's language, ...) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view is set up with a Contextual Filter for language, this should work:

```
print views_embed_view($viewname, $display_id, $languagecode);
```

Comment: There is already a contextual filter for taxonomy; and it works fine. But not for language. Don't know why!

Comment: You may want to clone the view display, add a contextual filter for language in the new display, remove the "Current user's language" filter for the new display, and then call this new display instead?

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: What have you got for contextual filters, and what variables are you calling views_embed_view with?

Comment: $res = views_embed_view("news_block", "block_1", "my-taxonomy-term", "fr");

also tried with: $res = views_embed_view("news_block", "block_1", array("my-taxonomy-term", "fr"));

for contextual filter, I tried even  to provide a default fixed value("fr"); and still no working;

Comment: Does it still pull English content, or nothing?

Comment: It returns french nodes - but how do I return french nodes && undefined lang nodes?

Comment: Some fields (like taxonomy terms) have "allow multiple values" in the "More" section of the contextual filter. Unfortunately I don't think Language does.

Comment: it works for language too; in contextual filters, at "Provide default value" choose "PHP Code" - for value, I used: "return array("fr", "und");";

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add "Filter criteria-- Content:Language(current User's language.)". This will solve our problem.